# How to get ColorPalette in color picker component

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6, color-picker

Am working on Flash CS 6. Am using color picker component but when ever i click on color picker it is displaying just some list of colors.But i need rainbow color palette and its functionality.Is it possible to do ? If is there any way tel me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the getter/setter colors (Array) of the class [ColorPicker](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/ColorPicker.html) *Gets or sets the array of custom colors that the ColorPicker component provides.*

You can also customize your ColorPicker using [setStyle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f1d.html)

```
 import fl.controls.ColorPicker;

 const RAINBOW_COLORS:Array = [0x6c2a7d, 0x9ed8f5, 0x0093d0, 0xfee96c, 0xef4135];

 var colorPicker:ColorPicker = new ColorPicker();
 colorPicker.colors = RAINBOW_COLORS;
 colorPicker.selectedColor = RAINBOW_COLORS[0];

 colorPicker.setStyle('columnCount', 7); 
 colorPicker.setStyle('swatchWidth', 12); 
 colorPicker.setStyle('swatchHeight', 12); 
 colorPicker.setStyle('swatchPadding', 2); 
 colorPicker.setStyle('backgroundPadding', 2); 
 colorPicker.setStyle('textPadding', 7);

 addChild(colorPicker);
```

[image]